# Rails: Generating Acts_as_Taggable_On tag counts from collection of tagged objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, collections, methods, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a site with Thinking Sphinx set up to return search results for Product names, tags, descriptions, etc. Works fine.

However, when I get a group of search results back from TS, I get a "no method" error when trying to get tag_counts from Acts_as_Taggable_On. I've found that the error extends to a range of situations where I might call tag_counts method on a collection of tagged items.

These work:

```
Owner.first.products.all.tag_counts
Product.where(:color => 'white').tag_counts
Product.first.tag_counts
```

But these don't:

```
Product.all.tag_counts
Product.search('white').to_a.tag_counts
```

(The latter calls a Thinking Sphinx search that returns a TS search collection.)

They come back with some variant of this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `tag_counts' for #<Array:0x00000101585280>
```

I have a vague idea this is some kind of proxy method thing where it's getting properly associated on the former calls but not the latter.

Anyone have suggestions on how I can ensure that an array of tagged objects has the tag_counts method available?

Answer (score 0):

`Product.all` returns an array and you're trying to run the method `tag_counts` on that array which won't work, as the array won't have that method.

What you're probably wanting to do is:

```
Product.tag_counts
```

It should return the tag counts for all products.

Comment: Okay, but what if I'm trying to run it on the array of results being returned by Thinking Sphinx when I call Product.search('foo'), or any other arbitrary array of Products?

Comment: Product.search('white').tag_counts should work fine if there is a class method called tag_counts on the product class.